# How to get data from joystick controller generator in Unity C#

Tags: airconsole

I created a joystick using the AirConsole controller generator, and it says that it sends this to the screen:

```
{
    joystick-left: {
        pressed: true|false,
        message: { x: Number, y: Number }
    }
}
```

Now I don't know how to parse this in Unity. Here's what I tried:

```
void OnMessage(int receivedID, JToken receivedData)
{
    bool pressed = (bool)receivedData["pressed"];
    float directionX = (float)receivedData["message"]["x"];
    float directionY = (float)receivedData["message"]["y"];
}
```

When I try to cast pressed as a bool, it gives me ArgumentNullException: Argument cannot be null. I also don't know what syntax I'm supposed to use to get the joystick direction.

How can I parse the information into C# Unity?

Answer (score 2):

I am not familiar with C# or Unity at all, but you have to do s.t. like:

```
// Sorry, I don't know the type, but assume its 'JToken'
JToken joystick_data = (JToken)receivedData["joystick-left"];

// And then to get the other params:
bool pressed = (bool)joystick_data["pressed"];
float directionX = (float)joystick_data["message"]["x"];
// ...
```